# Bluemix: Static via Nginx, Proxying to standalone Jar (with embedded jetty)

Tags: nginx, jar, proxy, ibm-cloud

I have a standalone Jar that listens on a port (embedded Jetty listening on 4567, a la Spark framework), and I have a static front-end (JS/CSS/Imgs/HTML) that I want to deploy into Nginx, and the proxy a certain requests to the Java app listening on 4567.

Best way to do this on Bluemix?

Comment: Does this Standalone Jar ( Jerry server) need to be private or public?

Comment: @vmovva It should be private, only because it has no purpose but to act as the API backend for the static app.  thx